# How to push item into array without removing last element

Tags: javascript, push, element

when sameFriends = [];

'dick', 'rex', 'james' gets push in

when I added 'golf', //output remove james

How can I add push in the same element from aFriend and bFriend without removing any?

```
let aFriend = ['dick', 'rex', 'james', 'tom', 'jack'];
let bFriend = ['dick', 'rex', 'james', 'jake'];
let sameFriend = ['golf'];

for (let i = 0; i < aFriend.length; i++){
  for (let k = 0; k < bFriend.length; k++){
    if (aFriend[i] === bFriend[k]){
      sameFriend.push(bFriend[k]);
      console.log(sameFriend[k]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code although can be bettered but works correctly. I see this output : ["golf","dick","rex","James"]. What do you expect?

Comment: console.log(sameFriend[k]);
The index k is for array bFriend not sameFriend witch is not the same size...

Comment: You can do this with one line : console.log(sameFriend.concat(aFriend.filter(item => bFriend.indexOf(item) >= 0)));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code as below:

```js
let aFriend = ['dick', 'rex', 'james', 'tom', 'jack'];
let bFriend = ['dick', 'rex', 'james', 'jake'];
let sameFriend = ['golf'];

for (let i = 0; i < aFriend.length; i++){
    for (let k = 0; k < bFriend.length; k++){
        if (aFriend[i] === bFriend[k]){
        sameFriend.push(bFriend[k]); //Here sameFriend array will have all elements which are same
       // console.log(sameFriend);
        }
    }
}
console.log(sameFriend);
```

Comment: Thanks @FZs just reread the details and updated code to reflect the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:
Change

```
console.log(sameFriend[k]);
```

To

```
console.log(bFriend[k]);
```

and add

```
console.log(sameFriend);
```

before entering 'for loop'.

The element you push into sameFriend is not stored at kth index of it.
That is why James didn't get printed.

Method 2:

Remove the console statement inside the 'for loop' and add

```
console.log(sameFriend);
```

at the end of the code to print all elements of sameFriend

Comment: I want it to print the similar names in aFriend and bFriends and including the element in sameFriend. That's why I'm using .push()

Comment: Either You can print the elements of sameFriend before 'for loop' and then proceed with 'for loop' with change I have mentioned OR add "console.log(sameFriend)" at the end of the code and remove console statement inside the 'for loop'.